# Kernels of Iterated Bounded Linear Functional Stabilize in Banach Space

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, operator-theory

I have that in a Banach space $V$, each $v \in V$ has a non-negative integer $n$ such that $T^{(n)}(v) = 0$ where $T^{(n)}$ is the $n$th iterate of $T$. I want to show that there exists some $N$ such that $T^{(N)}(v) = 0$ for all $v\in V$. I know this is equivalent to saying that the chain $\ker(T) \subset \ker(T^{(2)}) \subset \cdots$ stabilize.

I've thought about producing a contradiction involving the operator norm of $T$, which is assumed finite, but I haven't made any progress. Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$V=\bigcup_n \{x:T^{(n)} (x)=0\}$. By Baire Category Theorem there exists $n$ such that the kernel of $T^{(n)}$ has  a interior point. No proper subspace of a normed linear space can have an interior point, so this kernel must be $V$, as required.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more on how Baire Category Theorem implies the existence of that $n$? I can't seem to connect the statement of the theorem to this situation.

Comment: @Dalop: The kernel of $T^{(n)}$ is closed.  If it has no interior point then it is nowhere dense.  If this is true for all $n$, then $V$ is a countable union of nowhere dense sets, i.e. is meager (first category) which is precisely what Baire says a Banach space cannot be.